# Make LI have active state when input is focussed using css

Tags: html, css, input, focus

Is there a way to make an `<li>` have an *active state* when an input field is focussed using **CSS** only? If not, any suggestions on the best way to go about achieving this?

**See live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W5LzP/**

In the example, I want the background colour of the `LI` to stay yellow when the user clicks in the input field.

Example **HTML**:

```
<ol>
    <li>
    <label for="first_name">Your first name</label>
    <input name="first_name" placeholder="Type Your First Name" /></li>

    <li>
    <label for="lastt_name">Your last name</label>
    <input name="last_name" placeholder="Type Your Last Name" />
    </li>

    <li>
    <label for="email_address">Your first name</label>
    <input name="email_address" placeholder="Type Your Email Address" />
    </li>

    <li>
    <label for="country">Your country</label>
    <input name="country" placeholder="Select your country from the drop down list" />         
    </li>
</ol>
```

Example **CSS**:

```
ol li label{
    display:block;
}

ol li{
    margin-bottom:8px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

ol li:hover{
    background-color:#090;
}

ol li:active{
    background-color:#FF9;
}

ol li input:focus{
    border:1px solid #99C;
    background-color:#99F;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS can only select descendants, it can't select ancestors (perhaps it should for the reason you have outlined).

You would have to use JavaScript, look at [parentNode](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/parentNode) property.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0, inputsLength = inputs.length; i < inputsLength; i++) {

    inputs[i].onfocus = function() {
        this.parentNode.className += 'active';
    }

    inputs[i].onblur = function() {
        this.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.className.replace(/\bactive\b/, '');
    }

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/KUPPv/).

Comment: Thanks for the link alex. Are you able to provide an example/explanation of how I might be able to use the parentNode to get my above example to work?

Comment: Just checked out your example and it works perfectly! Thanks heaps for your help =D

Comment: @Dan No worries, and one day maybe they will support ancestor selecting :)

Comment: @alex, We can only hope =P Cheers again!

Comment: @alex, Just a friend rewrite your javascript to jQuery - seems to work really well: $('input').focus(function () {
     $(this).addClass('active');
    }).blur(function () {
     $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

Comment: @Dan Yeah, jQuery makes this stuff much easier, and I would have written that if you tagged your question `[jquery]`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately css doesn't support parent selectors.
So the only way to do it is to use javascript like the jQuery [parent method.](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: You should consider using a JavaScript framework like JQuery, instead of using the `parentNode` JavaScript function directly - since it will provide more consistent results across a wider variety of browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jordan. If you were able to supply an example of how to achieve the above example using the parent method like @Alex did, I would have awarded you the answer. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @theTRON What browsers are inconsistent with `parentNode` ?